# XPath How to Get Posts Separately

Tags: xpath

How can i get texts with xpath separately?

Code i tried only gets 1 with all info instead of separate:

- Post xpath: div
- Title xpath: ./p/strong/child::node()
- Desc xpath: ./ul/child::node()

Desired:

1. Title1

   Desc1
2. Title2

   Desc2

Got:

1. Title1 Title2

   Desc1 Desc2

HTML:

```
<div>
<p><strong>Title1</strong></p>
<ul>
<li>Desc1</li>
</ul>
<p><strong>Title2</strong></p>
<ul>
<li>Desc2</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what framework are you using for this?  What language?  Please edit the question and show a [mcve].  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what your "Desired" example is representing with pairs labeled 1 and 2, but if you are just trying to select each title text followed by its immediate following ul/li text you can use an expression such as:

```
//div/p/(
  ./normalize-space(string()), 
  ./(following-sibling::ul[1])/normalize-space(string()))
```

For each `p` it selects the entire text content of the `p` as string and then selects the immediately following `ul` sibling of the `p` and selects its entire string content.  This can be easily refined to only select `p/strong` content (instead of all of the `p`) and similar for `ul/li`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using a rss creator "politepol" to get inform updates. I need the parts as title with desc. 
I couldn't get **ul's below p's** as desc of this html. If i put the title "p/strong" as post i'm able to get all titles seperately. https://i.ibb.co/jyHTJbX/image.png

Working example of other feed with both title+desc: https://i.ibb.co/ByygX2s/image.png

structure of my html: https://i.ibb.co/kMYrJGg/image.png